# I can't seem to solve an IF() false positive in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Attached is a bowling sheet I have been working on to figure out my averages, and any "free game awards" I may get, as well as patches, etc...

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/excel/Bowling.xlsx

I am getting a false positive in column S.

[image]

Up till S12 the formula seems to work, in where there is a blank, and it shows me getting over 500.

The formula is:

`=IF($E12>499,"X","")`

Something simple and sweet or so I thought.

Now $E12 has this formula in it, which I don't see why it should affect it at all:

`=IF(D12<>0,SUM($B12:$D12),"")`

I tried using ISBLANK, but it seems to blow up in my face and not show anything.  If someone can help me it would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @brettdj: it sometimes depends on how tricky the formula could be :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on

Comment: @Jmax Well, in that case we don't need a Maths forum here either :) In the Excel world at least the distinction between "standard Excel" and VBA/XLM is well delineated.

Comment: @brettdj if Excel Formula questions are not meant to be asked here, why is there an excel-formula tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler alternative

```
=IF(N($E12)>499,"X","")
```

Comment: Ha +1 - I always forget that `N()` does something other than let you comment in a cell. Funny how I usually end up liking your solutions more than mine!

Answer (score 3):

Try this (in `E9`):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E9),IF($E9>499,"X",""),"")
```

This is likely a type comparison issue, so this only compares if the cell is actually a number.

Comment: I always forget about ISNUMBER, it seems to me that anything written in excel unless otherwise stated should be a number...  Thanks.